# Suggest best way for asynchronous loading in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, telerik-grid, asynchronous

I am developing a report (ASP.NET page) using Telerik RAD Grid controls and update panels. I have 3 filters to load the report. I am updating the report based on the filter selection.

I have 3 sections in my report. Each section contains 3 RAD grids and data is from different data sources. I am done with the report development and working fine but the page load time is > 45 seconds. I need to reduce the page load time to < 15 seconds. Suggest me the best approach to load 3 sections data asynchronously.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Is it possible to break it in iframes and add more than web thread to server your users (web garden).

Comment: No i cannot break into iframes.

Comment: @stephen776, can u please elaborate how can i use update panels to achieve this?

Comment: Did you saw this demo? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/databinding/defaultcs.aspx